# Spring Security ACL - cache configuration

Tags: grails, acl, ehcache

I try to update the spring-security-acl plugin in my Grails project from spring-security-acl:4.2.20.RELEASE to spring-security-acl:6.1.6. I see that the class "org.springframework.security.acls.domain.EhCacheBasedAclCache" is no longer exist in this version, I want to replace it by "org.springframework.security.acls.domain.SpringCacheBasedAclCache", but I encounter many problems, need help in updating the configuration of cache for the ACLs :

```
private configureCoreBeans = { conf ->

        // acl cache
        aclCacheManager(EhCacheManagerFactoryBean) {
            cacheManagerName = 'spring-security-acl-cache-' + UUID.randomUUID()
        }
        ehcacheAclCache(EhCacheFactoryBean) {
            cacheManager = ref('aclCacheManager')
            cacheName = 'aclCache'
        }
        aclCache(EhCacheBasedAclCache, ref('ehcacheAclCache'), ref('aclPermissionGrantingStrategy'), ref('aclAuthorizationStrategy'))

...

}
```

Need help in updating the configuration of cache for the ACLs

Comment: I get this error when i just changed EhCacheBasedAclCache by SpringCacheBasedAclCache : 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCache': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Could not convert argument value of type [net.sf.ehcache.Cache] to required type [org.springframework.cache.Cache]